# Need guidance for an approach to save multiple toggle buttons data without the submit button

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi all I'm trying to find a good solution to save the form data that has multiple toggle button ,but no submit button.

Say for example I have a form with 4 toggle buttons as 1)User(on/off) 2)Student(on/off) 3)Admin(on/off) 4)Client(on/off) so the ways to save the data for this toggle buttons would be in two ways as per my approach they are as below

1)OnChange event of each toggle make a call to save api
2)have a setTimeOut of say 2-3sec before sending the request to save api,and in that time if some other toggle value is changed merge both changes and send a single call to save api.

But both the approaches have there drawbacks
1)In the first approach the calls would be too much as toggle buttons count increases in future
2)In the second approach ,suppose if user closes the tab or browser then we have to check onUnload and make a save call and that can sometime be a source of error

Request if someone can help me with a better approach for the above scenario,and I'm using Angular12 for front-end and Nodejs as backend

Comment: Is it ok for you and the expected UX if you make all toggle buttons disabled when one is toggled, and enable them again when the call to api returns?

Comment: @MishaMashina cant disable other toggle buttons

Comment: Just to be clear: can't disable - as in some convention is stopping you, or you don't want to - because you don't want such UX?

Comment: Don't wait 3 sec. In that time I could have hit a button and exited the app believing the data changed. Or else. (***Edit:*** now I read that you do too realize that issue! :) )

Comment: Ya such UX isn't  approved hence I cant @MishaMashina

Comment: I don't see any problem of instantly submitting the data on button "click" to the backend. And eventually show in a tooltip "Saving data..."  and show "User updated" (or eventual errors) when the server responds.

Comment: Is the result of a single toggle immediately visible to the user and depends on api's call return? For example: is it a situation in which I toggle 'Student/on' and expected api call returns something that affects my options on that page?

If not, then you can save toggle changes in some var, then call api just once, when the user changes page for example.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sure will try to show the suggested message in toaster

Comment: @MishaMashina at present no such things

Comment: As @Roko C. Buljan said - there would be an issue with timeouts if the user closes the app, and it would be a problem in the approach I suggested too. So, yes, as he said - maybe it's best to just submit to backend as soon as the button is toggled. After all, the user will get a toast msg and will know that he did what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

what if you create a function with all the buttons?
I mean like this on your `.ts` file:

```
mainButton(){
//call the other 4 button functions here
this.userButton()
this.studentButton()
this.AdminButton()
this.ClientButton()
}
```

and on your main button, you do this:

```
<button (click)="mainButton()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Like one button to submit what's toggled in inidividual toggle buttons, and not a submit after each individual button's toggled? That's a good idea if it suits the expected UX and required UI.

Comment: Ya but this would need the submit button ,which is not the case in current scenario